# How to prevent a method from being invoked?

Tags: java

How can I prevent a method from being invoked? It's in a class imported from a jar and hence, I cannot edit the class.

**Reason** : *I want to prevent it since that method calls another REST API and gets few values from there which I don't require. If there is any way to surpass the http call, that would also work.*

**Code Example :**

```
public class class_name {
  public void method_name() {
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
  }
  public void method1() {
  }
  public void method2() {
  }
  public void method3() {
  }
}
```

I want to prevent `method2()` from getting invoked. Is there any way to do this? Since, I need to use this class just without that method.

Also, the class here is also being internally called by another class imported from the jar.

Comment: Not without some ugly hacks.

Comment: The requirement by itself is questionable and the question does not disclose the **why**.

Comment: Put a wrapper around the class that prevent calling method2.

Comment: @Sneha Chacko Why you want to prevent it ?

Comment: I want to prevent it since that method calls another rest api and gets few values from there which I don't require. If there is any way to surpass the http call, that would also work.

Comment: @SnehaChacko Then, you can simply comment that method call. Will that be useful to you ?

Comment: @AnishB. I can't edit the code since its imported from the jar.

Answer (score 1):

Because the method is called from other classes in the jar, you might need to patch the class at runtime. This is usually a bad idea, and a better way would be to edit the class file in the jar, creating a new jar.

The easiest way to redefine the class at runtime is with [ByteBuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/).
This code should do the trick:

```
ByteBuddyAgent.install();
new ByteBuddy()
    .redefine(class_name.class)
    .method(named("method2"))
    .intercept(StubMethod.INSTANCE)
    .make()
    .load(class_name.class.getClassLoader(), ClassReloadingStrategy.fromInstalledAgent());
```

While should work, it might be a better idea is to just remove all the code from the method in the jar file by patching the bytecode.

Comment: Before you call into the library. Best would be in main.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Javassist` or any other third party.

**Here, I'm showing it with the Javassist.**

```
Javassist deals with Java bytecode through .class files.
```

---

If you have a Maven project, then add the dependency to the `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the jar from here : [mvnrepository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javassist/javassist/3.12.1.GA/)

---

**I have provided a code example for understanding :**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

class class_name {
    public static void method_name() {
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
    }

    public static void method1() {
        System.out.println("In method1");
    }

    public static void method2() {
        System.out.println("In method2");
    }

    public static void method3() {
        System.out.println("In method3");
    }
}

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, IOException {
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass ctClass = pool.get("test.class_name");
        ctClass.defrost();
        CtMethod ctMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("method_name");
        ctMethod.setBody("{ method1();\r\n" + "method3(); }");
        ctClass.writeFile(".");
        ctClass.toClass();
        class_name className = new class_name();
        class_name.method_name();
    }

}
```

**Output :**

```
In method1
In method3
```

The library has many functionalities. So, do read the documentation.

**See Javassist Documentation : [Javassist Doc](https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)**

Hope this helps you.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with Aspects.

Following example is for Spring AOP implementation:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MethodCallPreventAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.thirdpartylib.class_name.method2(..))")
    public void thirdParty() {
    }

    @Around("thirdParty()")
    public Object preventInvocation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
         // return pjp.proceed(); // original behaviour
         return null; // invocation is bypassed
    }
}
```

To make it works just put `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation on any configuration class (`@Configuration`) and make sure that `MethodCallPreventAspect` is discoverable through component scan

More on AOP - https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can try by extending the class and provide you own implementation by overriding its method like,

```
// Class in jar
class Dummy {
      public void method_name(){
            method1();
            method2();
            method3();
          }
          public void method1(){
              System.out.println("method 1 invoked from Dummy");
          }
          public void method2(){
              System.out.println("method 2 invoked from Dummy");
          }
          public void method3(){
              System.out.println("method 3 invoked from Dummy");
          }

}


//Your class
public class Test3 extends Dummy {

    @Override
    public void method_name() {
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
    }

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        super.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2() {
        // No call from here
    }

    @Override
    public void method3() {
        super.method3();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Use you own class' objects to use jar class methods
        Test3 test = new Test3();
        test.method_name();
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! :) But here in my case, the class in which i need to prevent the call is also being called internally by another class imported from the jar.

Comment: Please mention this in the question itself for better understanding.
And, if the classes are being called internally then I see only two ways to get your desired behavior,  
1. Implementing the functionality yourself.  
2. Modify and update the class in jar (Not recommended)

Comment: The method I want to prevent from being invoked makes an HTTP request